# How to add additional attributes to a sitemap?

Tags: metadata, sitemap

I am generating a sitemap that conforms to [sitemaps.org's protocol](http://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
   <url>
      <loc>http://www.example.com/</loc>
      <lastmod>2005-01-01</lastmod>
      <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
      <priority>0.8</priority>
   </url>
</urlset>
```

Since I'm already generating a sitemap, I also wanted to use this URL/file for other things, like getting page titles and descriptions.  Is it possible (and legal format) to add a title/description anywhere in this format, and if so, how?

Comment: What do you want to add the additional info for? It is only worth doing if you have some search engine actually reading the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on what you want, but the short answer is no for XML sitemaps / http://sitemaps.org.

There are Google sitemap extensions, but then you have to use those specifications.